# Pragmatic Hello Android, Inflating seetings from XML to view in current activity

Tags: android

I am using method `addPreferenceFromResources()` to read the settings definition from XML file and inflate them into views in the current activity. but it is giving me an error and saying that this method is deprecated in Android now. Please help me to learn a new method to perform this task.

Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class prefs extends PreferenceActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: "Inflating seetings"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you start using sdk 3.0. They somehow changed the way to present preferences screen with new `fragments` feature. If you're not targeting tablets with your app, then old `addPreferencesFromResource` still works.

If you want to target tablets, then as the doc says(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) take a look at `PreferenceFragment` class.